# Cross domain error on Ajax call, Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, yii2

Here is simplified version of my probem.

I try to make a simple ajax call on a view to specific controller/action url and expecting json response.

**views/artwork/ajax.js**

```
ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/index.php?r=artwork/search",
    data: { "globalSearch": "somesearchterm" }
});
```

An action that correspond to the request, in this case, `actionSearch`, just simply return back the parameter's value `globalSearch` as response.

**Controllers/ArtworkController.php**

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $sterm = Yii::$app->$request->post('globalSearch');

        $res = array(
            'logicresult' => $sterm,
            'success' => true,
        );

        return $res;
    }
}
```

However, I got an jquery crossdomain error. what have i done wrong?

Chrome Console Log

```
POST http://localhost/index.php?r=artwork%2Fsearch 500 (Internal Server Error)
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4handleAjaxLink @ajax.js:19
n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 2):

The 500 (internal server error) means something went wrong on the server's side.

it is not cross domain error . error is in your PHP code.

you forgot to add close `}` for if condition ( AS per code mention in Question for  action `actionSearch` ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's just accidentally removed during my question posting. There is already `}` in my code. 
Here I edit the question according to your reply.